# Jmeter - load testing 200 concurrent - users,how much bandwidth is required to perform load test

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, bandwidth

Jmeter - load testing 200 concurrent - users checking scenarios like video viewing, pdf viewing etc, - how much bandwidth is required to perform load test

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we are not able to answer as it depends on requests and responses sizes and this is something  **only you** can measure.

If you need the overall idea and example steps on how you can calculate this, here is the simplest method:

1. Configure your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to run with 1 thread (virtual user) and 1 loop (iteration)
2. Run your JMeter test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```
3. Once your test finishes - open the `result.csv` file using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en/excel) or equivalent and sum up all values from `bytes` and `sentBytes` columns. This will allow you to roughly calculate how much traffic will your test generate

   [image: JMeter bandwidth]

   In my example 3 [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers produce `9816583` bytes of inbound and outbound traffic with is ~ 9.5 kilobytes which in its turn around 9 megabytes per one virtual user per one iteration.

So in my case test for 200 virtual users given 1 iteration will produce 1.8 GB of traffic.

Comment: thanks dmitri for your answer, so in your test what is the minimum bandwidth you will prefer 10 mpbs, 30 mbps, etc how much mbps you will prefer?

Comment: 2) I am targeting concurrent users ram up is 0 then users 200 or 300  m planning to cover some video rendering scenarios too if we don’t have enough bandwidth time will be increased right? so in this case there is no problem with application or server  we dont have enough bandwidth for the virtual users right? so after your calculation how you will decide on your mbps(bandwidth speed?.